# Layer Navigation - Maximum Number of Price Intervals - Not Working

Tags: magento

For Layer Navigation Setting, I have set Default Price Navigation Step, which is working fine. However, Maximum Number of Price Intervals are not working.

I input this to 4 but it has no impact on frontend and shows price intervals till maximum price value. (10 price intervals)

I would like to see up to 4 intervals, with last one display with $300 and above

Current Problem: 0-$100, $100- $200, $200- $300, $300 - $400, $400- $500, ......... till last catalog price.

Desired Output: 0-$100, $100- $200, $200 - $300, $300 and above.

Anyone who could help?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, its working fine [image]

I assume you set the configuration like above. If you still get it do the following

1. reindex the entire catalog by following system -> index management
2. clear cache folder /var/cache
3. disable redis or memcache or any other caching if enabled
4. Disable compilation system -> tools -> compilation
5. enable debugging follow system -> developer -> logsettings and make sure there are no exceptions thrown look into /var/log/exception.log for errors
6. disable any custom extension (layer navigation related)
7. enable default theme

You will see the price navigation like
 [image]

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html